# Extract column data from csv file based on row values

Tags: csv, awk, sed, data-extraction

I am trying to use awk/sed to extract specific column data based on row values. My actual files have 15 columns and over 1,000 rows (From a .csv file.)

Simple EXAMPLE: Input; a cdv file with a total of 5 columns and 100 rows. Output; data from column 2 through 5 based on specific row values from column 2. (I have a specific list of the row values I want the operator to filter out. The values are numbers.)

File looks like this:

```
"Date","IdNo","Color","Height","Education"
"06/02/16","7438","Red","54","4"
"06/02/16","7439","Yellow","57","3"
"06/03/16","7500","Red","55","3"
```

Recently Tried in AWK:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 
#I need to extract a full line when column 2 has a specific 5 digit    value
awk '\
BEGIN { awk -F "," \    
{
    if ( $2 == "19650" ) { \
       {print $1 "," $6} \ 
}
exit }     

chmod u+x PPMDfUN.AWK
```

The operator response:

```
/var/folders/1_/drk_nwld48bb0vfvdm_d9n0h0000gq/T/PPMDfUN-     489939602.998.AWK.command ; exit;
/usr/bin/awk: syntax error at source line 3 source file    /private/var/folders/1_/drk_nwld48bb0vfvdm_d9n0h0000gq/T/PPMDfUN-   489939602.997.AWK
context is
awk >>>  ' <<< 
/usr/bin/awk: bailing out at source line 17
logout
```

Output Example: I want full row lines based if column 2 equals 7439 & 7500.

```
“Date","IdNo","Color","Height","Education"
"06/02/16","7439","Yellow","57","3"
"06/03/16","7500","Red","55","3"
```

Comment: you want the solution is python or awk ?

Comment: Your question currently is very unclear. [edit] it to provide a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input **and expected output** plus what you have attempted so far. Also make sure your example is accurate, e.g. does the 3rd line of your input **really** contain `'7439',Yellow'` (no single quote before `Yellow'`)?

Comment: To Hani: Either is fine. I was in csh.

Comment: Your file is comma delimited, '\t' is for tab.  Also, the fields are single quoted, not double.  Finally, 19650 is a five digit number not four.

Comment: The syntax error is because you used some weird curly character (`“`) instead of the double quotes character (`"`) at the start of the assignment `-F “\t"` so awk didn't know what to do with it. You also have some other weird curly character (`’`) interlaced with the single quotes (`'`) in your sample input. In light of this and what @karakfa pointed out previously, [edit] your question so it makes sense and uses consistent, correct characters so you can help us to understand what you want so we can start to help you with a solution rather than still being on [ask] the question.

Comment: also make sure your input is a text file, `PPMD_ScriptPractice.xlsx` probably is not.  Your shebang says it's an awk script but the content is not.  Best if you run it on the commandline first and then convert to a script, either bash or awk and learn the difference.

Answer (score 0):

here you go...

```
 $ awk -F, -v q='"' '$2==q"7439"q' file

"06/02/16","7439","Yellow","57","3"
```

There is not much to explain, other than convenience variable `q` defined for double quotes helps to eliminate escaping.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Now, I have to get to print to an out_put_file (preferably .csv)

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'NR<2;$2~/7439|7500/' file
"Date","IdNo","Color","Height","Education"
"06/02/16","7439","Yellow","57","3"
"06/03/16","7500","Red","55","3"
```